# Insert SQL on based on field from ALL records

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have seen this done when moving a table, but it uses the entire select subquery as the values input. I need to do something similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO customer_alerts
  (message, customer_id) 
VALUES 
  ("Message HERE", (SELECT Customer.id from Customers as Customer))
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to insert multiple rows into `customer_alerts`, one per every row in `Customer`?

Comment: Yes. OMG Ponies answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO customer_alerts
  (message, customer_id) 
SELECT 'Message HERE', c.id 
  FROM CUSTOMERS c
```

You can statically define values in the `SELECT` clause.